# What is the relevance of Fresca in the show "The Boys"?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-boys

I am wondering what is the relevance of the Fresca drink in *The Boys*?

Is it just for comic relief or does it have a more devious use?

Is it for mind control?

Comment: I actually read some fan theory somewhere that Fresca is what caused The Deep's hallucinations i.e. his conversation with his gills. And this makes sense.

Comment: @aryansonwatikar In that episode the Archer/Eagle offers The Deep an infusion of hallucinogenic mushrooms to help him progress along his "spiritual journey", that must be that and not Fresca.

Comment: @wip I personally don't remember any mushrooms but sure that the fan theory said that it was Fresca causing the hallucinations. I need a S2 rewatch.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Unfortunately, none

[**It's an in-house joke by the writers**](https://www.cbr.com/the-boys-why-church-of-the-collective-obsessed-fresca/)..

> A simpler explanation of the abundance of Fresca has recently been offered by showrunner Eric Kripke, and it's not as exciting as fans once hoped. Kripke confirmed that the Fresca bit was a running gag in the writer's room that made its way into the finished scripts, stemming from a discussion over what Eagle would offer The Deep as a non-alcoholic beverage. This is due to the fact that many religious organizations dissuade their members from consuming alcohol, or engaging in excess with controlled substances.

and

> Then Fresca just came from...honestly, I wish there was a deeper thought than it just became this running joke. We were laughing because we were thinking about like, 'Okay, what does Eagle the Archer serve him to drink? Was it alcohol? No, no, he's in this cult, and they don't drink alcohol. What do they drink?' And I don't know who said it, but someone was like, 'Fresca! They drink Fresca!' And we just started laughing, because for some reason, it seems like the drink of cult members, which I think is going to be their new advertising slogan next year: The Drink of Cult Members. It just seemed like something they drink, and so we just started putting it in more and more. You'll see once you see the whole season, we keep that joke rolling all season long. [Laughs.] That Fresca joke does not stop. It is right up until the very, very end of the show, we had Church of the Collective members drinking Fresca.

<sup>[**Source**](https://www.cinemablend.com/television/2554104/the-boys-creator-talks-the-church-of-the-collective-and-explains-the-fresca-references)</sup>

Comment: Ugh, this nonsense is one of the reasons the second season was nowhere as good as it should have been.

Comment: @BCdotWEB IMHO both seasons were excellent, just that they were, uh, *different*?

Comment: I really thought there is a significance to the fresca, maybe this will change. TV series changes their story based on fan theory too.

Comment: Also, the fresca brang had a lot of free advertising, coca cola must be really happy. unless they put a negative connotation with it.

Comment: I would not say it is completely irrelevant then ; in the scene where Butcher meets Edgar face to face, what Edgar is drinking seems to be Fresca as well (it is served on top of ice cubes sprinkled with lime by one of the restaurant attendants..) ; this could be interpreted as a clue that Edgar has stronger ties with the Church of the Collective than appears (a member maybe).

Comment: @BCdotWEB - There has to be a deep, serious, earth-shaking reason for low-cal soda preference for a season to be good?